# why doesn't my flex-row work on my inner div

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm currently trying to position two divs next to each other horizontally, and my idea was to make use of flexbox, but adding the property `flex-row` doesn't seem to do anything and I can't figure out why.

How do I properly align the divs that contain "Test" next to each other horizontally?

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.card-body {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.media {
  width: 100%;
  border-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@0.5.2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card mx-auto flex justify-center">
  <div class="card-body my-auto">
    <div class="media bg-blue-600 flex-row">

      <div class="media-thumb w-10 h-10 bg-yellow-600 rounded-sm mx-auto">
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>

      <div class="media-body w-10 h-10 bg-red-600 rounded-sm mx-auto">
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, it looks different when I run it locally, compared to JSFiddle
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the class `flex-row` for the class `flex` in the parent container. See the working snippet below:

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.card-body {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.media {
  width: 100%;
  border-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@0.5.2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card mx-auto flex justify-center">
  <div class="card-body my-auto">
    <div class="media bg-blue-600 flex">

      <div class="media-thumb w-10 h-10 bg-yellow-600 rounded-sm mx-auto">
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>

      <div class="media-body w-10 h-10 bg-red-600 rounded-sm mx-auto">
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! How come flex-row didn't work?

Comment: Because this class does something else. Have a look in here https://tailwind.build/classes/flex/flex-row - please mark this as the correct answer if that solved your issue :)